# XML - Document cannot contain multiple root elements

Tags: xml

I was trying to merge with git, but it apparently caused a problem with the XML file making a project unavailable. I know nothing about XML.  Here is an excerpt of my file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="MetroFramework.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

Comment: All that XML needs to be inside another single element, if this is a ms build file then the root is <Project>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An XML documents must have a single root element.**  To solve your problem:

- Remove all root elements except for one, or
- Wrap all top-level elements in a single root element.

Until you ensure that your XML document has a single root element, your file will not be ***well-formed*** (and will not actually be XML).  Also, if your document is intended to follow a schema, make sure the root element and its contents (recursively) is ***valid*** according to the schema (XSD, DTD, etc).  For more on this, see [***well-formed vs invalid XML***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

As [Alex K points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592719/xml-document-cannot-contain-multiple-root-elements/44592896#comment76173272_44592719), your XML document looks like it's intended to be a [MSBuild Project file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx).