# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Team'. One of '{"":Player}' is expected

Tags: xml, xsd

this is my first time asking a question here so forgive me if this is not properly formatted.

can somebody please help me understand this error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Team'. One of '{"":Player}' is expected.

my .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>

<Teams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Homework3.xsd">

<Team Name="Cubs" Est="1876" State="Illinois" City="Chicago" FieldName="Wrigley Field" MascotName="Clark">
    <Player>
        <Name>Willson Contreras</Name>
        <BirthDate>1992-05-13</BirthDate>
        <Position>Catcher</Position>
        <RBIs>40</RBIs>
        <HRs>17</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.227</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>David Bote</Name>
        <BirthDate>1993-04-07</BirthDate>
        <Position>Second Base</Position>
        <RBIs>32</RBIs>
        <HRs>8</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.202</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Ian Happ</Name>
        <BirthDate>1994-08-12</BirthDate>
        <Position>Center Field</Position>
        <RBIs>48</RBIs>
        <HRs>19</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.214</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Jason Heyward</Name>
        <BirthDate>1989-08-09</BirthDate>
        <Position>Right Field</Position>
        <RBIs>27</RBIs>
        <HRs>7</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.213</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Patrick Wisdom</Name>
        <BirthDate>1991-08-27</BirthDate>
        <Position>Third Base</Position>
        <RBIs>50</RBIs>
        <HRs>25</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.239</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
</Team>
<Team Name="White Sox" Est="1900" State="Illinois" City="Chicago" FieldName="Guaranteed Rate Field" MascotName="Southpaw">
    <Player>
        <Name>Jose Abreu</Name>
        <BirthDate>1987-01-29</BirthDate>
        <Position>First Base</Position>
        <RBIs>103</RBIs>
        <HRs>28</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.265</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Leury Garcia</Name>
        <BirthDate>1991-03-18</BirthDate>
        <Position>Center Field</Position>
        <RBIs>46</RBIs>
        <HRs>3</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.255</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Brian Goodwin</Name>
        <BirthDate>1990-11-02</BirthDate>
        <Position>Center Field</Position>
        <RBIs>26</RBIs>
        <HRs>8</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.229</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Yasmani Grandal</Name>
        <BirthDate>1988-11-08</BirthDate>
        <Position>Catcher</Position>
        <RBIs>53</RBIs>
        <HRs>19</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.227</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Cesar Hernandez</Name>
        <BirthDate>1990-05-23</BirthDate>
        <Position>Second Base</Position>
        <RBIs>52</RBIs>
        <HRs>21</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.226</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
</Team>
<Team Name="Yankees" Est="1901" State="New York" City="New York City" FieldName="Yankee Stadium" MascotName="N/A">
    <Player>
        <Name>Anthony Rizzo</Name>
        <BirthDate>1989-08-08</BirthDate>
        <Position>First Base</Position>
        <RBIs>53</RBIs>
        <HRs>18</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.249</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Joey Gallo</Name>
        <BirthDate>1993-11-19</BirthDate>
        <Position>Right Field</Position>
        <RBIs>68</RBIs>
        <HRs>31</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.196</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Brett Gardner</Name>
        <BirthDate>1983-08-24</BirthDate>
        <Position>Left Field</Position>
        <RBIs>26</RBIs>
        <HRs>6</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.213</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Aaron Judge</Name>
        <BirthDate>1992-04-26</BirthDate>
        <Position>Right Field</Position>
        <RBIs>75</RBIs>
        <HRs>30</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.291</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>DJ LeMahieu</Name>
        <BirthDate>1988-07-13</BirthDate>
        <Position>Second Base</Position>
        <RBIs>54</RBIs>
        <HRs>9</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.268</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
</Team>
<Team Name="Dodgers" Est="1883" State="California" City="Los Angeles" FieldName="Dodgers Stadium" MascotName="N/A">
    <Player>
        <Name>Cody Bellinger</Name>
        <BirthDate>1995-07-13</BirthDate>
        <Position>Center Field</Position>
        <RBIs>32</RBIs>
        <HRs>9</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.165</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Mookie Betts</Name>
        <BirthDate>1992-10-07</BirthDate>
        <Position>Right Field</Position>
        <RBIs>47</RBIs>
        <HRs>19</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.266</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Albert Pujols</Name>
        <BirthDate>1980-01-16</BirthDate>
        <Position>First Base</Position>
        <RBIs>48</RBIs>
        <HRs>16</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.239</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Justin Turner</Name>
        <BirthDate>1984-11-23</BirthDate>
        <Position>Third Base</Position>
        <RBIs>71</RBIs>
        <HRs>21</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.279</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Trea Turner</Name>
        <BirthDate>1993-06-30</BirthDate>
        <Position>Shortstop</Position>
        <RBIs>58</RBIs>
        <HRs>21</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.319</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
</Team> 
<Team Name="Brewers" Est="1969" State="Wisconsin" City="Milwaukee" FieldName="American Family Field" MascotName="Bernie Brewer">
    <Player>
        <Name>Jackie Bradley Jr.</Name>
        <BirthDate>1990-04-19</BirthDate>
        <Position>Center Field</Position>
        <RBIs>29</RBIs>
        <HRs>6</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.169</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Eduardo Escobar</Name>
        <BirthDate>1989-01-05</BirthDate>
        <Position>Second Base</Position>
        <RBIs>73</RBIs>
        <HRs>24</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.256</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Omar Narvaez</Name>
        <BirthDate>1992-02-10</BirthDate>
        <Position>Catcher</Position>
        <RBIs>45</RBIs>
        <HRs>11</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.283</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Jace Peterson</Name>
        <BirthDate>1990-05-09</BirthDate>
        <Position>Second Base</Position>
        <RBIs>30</RBIs>
        <HRs>5</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.272</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Christian Yelich</Name>
        <BirthDate>1991-15-05</BirthDate>
        <Position>Left Field</Position>
        <RBIs>41</RBIs>
        <HRs>8</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.255</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
</Team>
<Team Name="Indians" Est="1894" State="Ohio" City="Cleveland" FieldName="Progressive Field" MascotName="Slider">
    <Player>
        <Name>Bobby Bradley</Name>
        <BirthDate>1996-05-29</BirthDate>
        <Position>First Base</Position>
        <RBIs>31</RBIs>
        <HRs>12</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.222</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Andres Gimenez</Name>
        <BirthDate>1998-07-24</BirthDate>
        <Position>Shortstop</Position>
        <RBIs>9</RBIs>
        <HRs>2</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.206</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Austin Hedges</Name>
        <BirthDate>1992-08-18</BirthDate>
        <Position>Catcher</Position>
        <RBIs>27</RBIs>
        <HRs>8</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.182</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Daniel Johnson</Name>
        <BirthDate>1995-07-11</BirthDate>
        <Position>Right Field</Position>
        <RBIs>5</RBIs>
        <HRs>4</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.230</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Oscar Mercado</Name>
        <BirthDate>1994-12-16</BirthDate>
        <Position>Left Field</Position>
        <RBIs>11</RBIs>
        <HRs>3</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.221</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
</Team>
<Team Name="Royals" Est="1969" State="Missouri" City="Kansas City" FieldName="Kauffman Stadium" MascotName="Sluggerrr">
    <Player>
        <Name>Hanser Alberto</Name>
        <BirthDate>1992-10-17</BirthDate>
        <Position>Third Base</Position>
        <RBIs>20</RBIs>
        <HRs>2</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.258</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Andrew Benintendi</Name>
        <BirthDate>1994-07-06</BirthDate>
        <Position>Left Field</Position>
        <RBIs>46</RBIs>
        <HRs>12</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.254</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Hunter Dozier</Name>
        <BirthDate>1991-08-22</BirthDate>
        <Position>Third Base</Position>
        <RBIs>39</RBIs>
        <HRs>10</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.202</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Nicky Lopez</Name>
        <BirthDate>1995-03-13</BirthDate>
        <Position>Shortstop</Position>
        <RBIs>34</RBIs>
        <HRs>1</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.290</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Whit Merrifield</Name>
        <BirthDate>1989-01-24</BirthDate>
        <Position>Second Base</Position>
        <RBIs>68</RBIs>
        <HRs>10</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.278</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
</Team>
<Team Name="Reds" Est="1881" State="Ohio" City="Cincinati" FieldName="Great American Ball Park" MascotName="Mr. Redlegs">
    <Player>
        <Name>Shogo Akiyama</Name>
        <BirthDate>1988-04-16</BirthDate>
        <Position>Left Field</Position>
        <RBIs>12</RBIs>
        <HRs>0</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.199</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Aristides Aquino</Name>
        <BirthDate>1994-04-22</BirthDate>
        <Position>Right Field</Position>
        <RBIs>20</RBIs>
        <HRs>9</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.195</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Tucker Barnhart</Name>
        <BirthDate>1991-01-07</BirthDate>
        <Position>Catcher</Position>
        <RBIs>43</RBIs>
        <HRs>7</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.269</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Asdrubal Cabrera</Name>
        <BirthDate>1985-11-13</BirthDate>
        <Position>Third Base</Position>
        <RBIs>41</RBIs>
        <HRs>7</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.235</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Nick Castellanos</Name>
        <BirthDate>1992-03-04</BirthDate>
        <Position>Right Field</Position>
        <RBIs>78</RBIs>
        <HRs>26</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.321</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
</Team>
<Team Name="Red Sox" Est="1901" State="Massachusetts" City="Boston" FieldName="Fenway Park" MascotName="Wally the Green Monster">
    <Player>
        <Name>Jonathan Arauz</Name>
        <BirthDate>1998-08-03</BirthDate>
        <Position>Second Base</Position>
        <RBIs>7</RBIs>
        <HRs>3</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.169</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Franchy Cordero</Name>
        <BirthDate>1994-09-02</BirthDate>
        <Position>Left Field</Position>
        <RBIs>9</RBIs>
        <HRs>1</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.189</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Bobby Dalbec</Name>
        <BirthDate>1995-06-29</BirthDate>
        <Position>First Base</Position>
        <RBIs>65</RBIs>
        <HRs>18</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.240</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Rafael Devers</Name>
        <BirthDate>1996-10-24</BirthDate>
        <Position>Third Base</Position>
        <RBIs>101</RBIs>
        <HRs>33</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.276</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Jose Iglesias</Name>
        <BirthDate>1990-01-05</BirthDate>
        <Position>Shortstop</Position>
        <RBIs>42</RBIs>
        <HRs>8</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.261</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
</Team>
<Team Name="Cardinals" Est="1882" State="Missouri" City="St. Louis" FieldName="Busch Stadium" MascotName="Fredbird">
    <Player>
        <Name>Nolan Arenado</Name>
        <BirthDate>1991-04-16</BirthDate>
        <Position>Third Base</Position>
        <RBIs>88</RBIs>
        <HRs>29</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.257</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Harrison Bader</Name>
        <BirthDate>1994-06-03</BirthDate>
        <Position>Center Field</Position>
        <RBIs>37</RBIs>
        <HRs>11</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.248</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Dylan Carlson</Name>
        <BirthDate>1998-10-23</BirthDate>
        <Position>Center Field</Position>
        <RBIs>48</RBIs>
        <HRs>13</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.259</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Matt Carpenter</Name>
        <BirthDate>1985-11-26</BirthDate>
        <Position>Second Base</Position>
        <RBIs>21</RBIs>
        <HRs>3</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.176</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name>Paul DeJong</Name>
        <BirthDate>1993-08-02</BirthDate>
        <Position>Shortstop</Position>
        <RBIs>40</RBIs>
        <HRs>16</HRs>
        <BattingAvg>.197</BattingAvg>
    </Player>
</Team>
```

my .xsd file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    
    <xs:simpleType name="RBIsType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
           <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
           <xs:maxInclusive value="150" />     
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name="NameType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
           <xs:pattern value="[A-Z][\-A-Za-z './]+" /> 
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name="EstType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
           <xs:pattern value="\d\d\d\d" /> 
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name="baType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
           <xs:minInclusive value=".000" />
           <xs:maxInclusive value=".500"    />     
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name="dateType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:element name="Player">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Name" type="NameType" />
                <xs:element name="BirthDate" type="dateType" />
                <xs:element name="Position" type="NameType" />
                <xs:element name="RBIs" type="RBIsType" />
                <xs:element name="HRs" type="RBIsType" />
                <xs:element name="BattingAvg" type="baType" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="Team">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Player" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Name" type="NameType" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="Est" type="EstType" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="State" type="NameType" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="City" type="NameType" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="FieldName" type="NameType" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="MascotName" type="NameType" use="optional" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="Teams">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Player" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
</xs:schema>
```

I have updated this post with more better, and hopefully easier to understand code. I am still receiving the same error message above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema says that a `Teams` element contains a sequence of `Player` elements. But in your XML instance, the `Teams` element contains a sequence of `Team` elements. So it's expecting to find a `Player` element, but it finds a `Team` element, which is why it complains saying

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'Team'. One of '{"":Player}' is expected.
```

Note that the notation `{"":Player}` means a `Player` element in no namespace. The reason it explains it this way is that this error is often caused by use of an incorrect namespace (but not in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134494/290085) because it has multiple root elements.  An XML document may only have [a single root element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44592719/290085https://stackoverflow.com/q/44592719/290085).

Your options to repair this problem:

1. Remove all `Team` elements after the first one, or
2. Wrap all `Team` elements in a single root element such as `Teams`.

Option #1 would be sufficient alone; option #2 would require the addition of the `Teams` wrapper element to your XSD.

Comment: sorry, i am new to this site and xml and pasted my code wrong. each Team is wrapped in a root element called Players. there are ten teams that fall under the root of players. does that makes sense?

Comment: No, not really, and wrapping the multiple `Team` elements with a `Players` element also contradicts your XSD as well.  The natural wrapper for `Team` elements would be a `Teams`, not a `Players`, wrapper element.

Comment: I have changed Players to Teams so that it makes sense. The root Teams contains 10 elements named Team. Each Team element contains 5 Player elements. Each Player elements contains 6 elements for stats (stats). My apologies for this code being confusing/frustrating.

Comment: If your problem is solved, great.  If not, I suggest that you update your question with your latest version of your XML, XSD, and error message if you require further help.