# What does the "Extra content at the end of the document" XML error message mean?

Tags: xml

I am getting the following error message on validating the file on several platforms.All the tags seem balanced to me, so the error is a bit confusing to me.

"Invalid XML: This page contains the following errors: error on line 3 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

The document is attached below.

```
<p><c><letter><or>କ</or></letter></c></p>

<entry>
<p><hw>କ—</hw></p>
<tr>Ka</tr>
<syn> <bengali>ক</bengali> <hindi>क</hindi></syn>
<gramGrp><p>ସଂ—</p>
<sense><p>ପ୍ରଥମ ବର୍ଗର ପ୍ରଥମ ବର୍ଣ୍ଣ; ପ୍ରଥମ ବ୍ୟଞ୍ଜନ ବର୍ଣ୍ଣ (ଏହାର
ଉଚ୍ଚାରଣ ସ୍ଥାନ କଣ୍ଠ। ଏହା କୌଣସି ଅକ୍ଷର ସଙ୍ଗେ ଯୁକ୍ତ
ହେଲେ, ସେହି ଅକ୍ଷର ତଳେ 'କ' ମାତ୍ରା ରୂପେ ବ୍ୟବହୃତ ହୁଏ।
କ ବର୍ଗର ପାଞ୍ଚ ଗୋଟି ଅକ୍ଷର। ଯଥା—କ, ଖ, ଗ, ଘ, ଙ)—
The first consonant of the Sanskrit and
the Oṟḍ̠iā alphabet.</p></sense></gramGrp>
<gramGrp><p>ସଂ. ବି, (କୈ ଧାତୁ=ଶବ୍ଦ କରିବା; ଦୀପ୍ତି ପାଇବା+କର୍ତ୍ତୃ. ଅ)—</p>
<sense><p>1। ବ୍ରହ୍ମା—1. Brahmā.</p>
<p>2। ବିଷ୍ଣୁ—2. Bishṇu.</p>
<p>3। ଶିବ—3. Ṡiba.</p>
<p>4। ବାୟୁ—4. Air.</p>
<p>5। ଯମ—5. J̄ama.</p>
<p>6। ସୂର୍ଯ୍ୟ—6. Sun.</p>
<p>7। ଆତ୍ମା—7. Soul.</p>
<p>8। ଅଗ୍ନି—8. Fire.</p>
<p>9। ପକ୍ଷୀ—9. Bird.</p>
<p>10। ଦକ୍ଷ ପ୍ରଜାପତି—10. Daksha Prajāpati.</p>
<p>11। ରୋଗ—11. Sickness; disease.</p>
<p>12। କାଳ—12. Time.</p>
<p>13। କନ୍ଦର୍ପ—13. Cupid.</p>
<p>14। ଦୀପ୍ତି—14. Lustre.</p>
<p>15। କେଶ—15. Hair.</p>
<p>16। ମୟୂର—16. Peacock.</p>
<p>17। ଶରୀର—17. Body.</p>
<p>18। ରାଜା—18. King.</p>
<p>19। ଶବ୍ଦ—19. Sound.</p>
<p>20। ଧନ—20. Money; riches.</p>
<p>21। ମନ—21. Mind.</p>
<p>22। ମସ୍ତକ—22. Head.</p>
<p>23। ସୁଖ—23. Happiness.</p>
<p>24। ଜଳ—24. Water.</p>
<p>[ଦ୍ର—ତନ୍ତ୍ରମତରେ ଏହି ଅକ୍ଷରର ବାମରେଖା ବ୍ରହ୍ମା, ଦକ୍ଷିଣ—
ରେଖା ବିଷ୍ଣୁ ଓ ଅଧୋରେଖା ରୁଦ୍ର; ମାତ୍ରା ସାକ୍ଷାତ ସରସ୍ୱତୀ ଓ
ମଧ୍ୟସ୍ଥଳର ଶୂନ୍ୟସ୍ଥାନ ସଦାଶିବ]</p></sense></gramGrp>
<gramGrp><p>ସଂ. ପ୍ରତ୍ୟୟ—</p>
<sense><p>1। ସ୍ୱାର୍ଥବୋଧକ (ଯଥା—ବାଳ+କ=ବାଳକ)—
1. (a Sanskrit suffix) Denoting
selfsame.</p>
<p>2। ଅଳ୍ପ ବା କ୍ଷୁଦ୍ରାର୍ଥବୋଧକ (ଯଥା—ମାଣବକ; ପୁତ୍ରକ;
ଅଶ୍ୱକ)—2. Denoting diminutive form.</p>
<p>3। ସହାର୍ଥତତ୍‌ପୁରୁଷ ବା ବହୁବ୍ରୀହି ସମାସରେ ସମସ୍ତପଦ
ଶେଷରେ ଯୁକ୍ତ ହୁଏ (ଯଥା—ସସ୍ତ୍ରୀକ; ଅରାଜକ;
ବିପତ୍ନୀକ)—3. Used in adjectival
compounds denoting, accompanied with.</p></sense></gramGrp>
<gramGrp><p>ଦେ. ଅ.—</p>
<sense><p>1। (ପଦ୍ୟ) (ସଂ. କିଳ)—
ପାଦ ପୂରଣ ପାଇଁ କ୍ରିୟା
ଶେଷରେ ପ୍ରଯୁକ୍ତ—
1. Redundant letter added
to a verb.</p>
<verse><p>ପୂର୍ବ ଦୁଃଖ ଅପମାନ କଲେକ ସ୍ମରଣ
ବିଷପାନ, ଜତୁଗୃହ, ବନବିବାସନ। ରାଧାନାଥ, ବେଣୀସଂହାର।</p></verse>
<p>2। (ପଦ୍ୟ) (କ୍ରିୟା ସଙ୍ଗେ ଯୁକ୍ତ ହେଲେ କ୍ରିୟାର ନିଶ୍ଚୟାର୍ଥ
ବୁଝାଏ)—ନିଶ୍ଚେଁ; ଟି—2. Certainly; surely.</p>
<verse><p>ଧନୁ ଶର ତଳେ ଥୋଇ ଲାଗିବାକ ଆସ । ପୀତାମ୍ବର, ନୃସିଂହପୁରାଣ।</p></verse>
<p>3। (କାଳବାଚକ ଶବ୍ଦ ସଙ୍ଗେ ଯୁକ୍ତ) ମାତ୍ର; କେବଳମାତ୍ର—
3. Only; merely.</p>
<verse><p>ରୁଣ୍ଡ ହୋଇଲେ ଗଡ଼ ଦ୍ୱାରେ,
ଆଜକ ରହିବେ ତୋଟାରେ। ଜଗନ୍ନାଥ, ଭାଗବତ।</p></verse>

<pb n="1196"/>
<p>4। ସଂଖ୍ୟା ବା ସମାହାରବାଚକ ଶଦ୍ଦ ପରେ ଏକବଚନାର୍ଥରେ
ବ୍ୟବହୃତ; ଏକ—4. Single; one.</p>
<p>(ଯଥା—ପଣକ; କାହାଣକ; ସେରକ; ଜଣକ; ମାଣକ; ଇତ୍ୟାଦି।)</p>
<verse><p>ଧୋବା ମଳିକ, ସଙ୍ଖାଳି କରିଛି ଝିଅ ହଳିକ। ଢଗ।</p></verse>
<p>5। (କାଳବାଚକ ଶଦ୍ଦ ପରେ ବ୍ୟବହୃତ) ଏକମାତ୍ର; ଏକ
ସଂଖ୍ୟକ—5. One only.</p>
<p>(ଯଥା—କ୍ଷଣକ; ମୁହୂର୍ତ୍ତକ ଇତ୍ୟାଦି।)</p>
<verse><p>ନିମିଷକେ ପ୍ରାଣ ତାର ପକାନ୍ତିଟି ଦହି। ପୀତାମ୍ବର, ନୃସିଂହପୁରାଣ।</p></verse>
<p>6। (ଅନ୍ୟ ବିଶେଷ୍ୟ ପଦ ପରେ ଯୁକ୍ତ) ପ୍ରତ୍ୟେକ—
6. Each; every.</p>
<verse><p>ରୋମକେ ବ୍ରହ୍ମାଣ୍ଡ ତୋହର। ଭୂପତି, ପ୍ରେମପଞ୍ଚାମୃତ।</p></verse>
<p>7। (ବ୍ୟାପ୍ତ୍ୟର୍ଥକ) ସମସ୍ତ; ଯାକ—
7. All; the whole.</p>
<p>(ଯଥା—ପୋଖରୀକ ମାଛ ଲୁଟି ନେଲା; ଏତେକ; ସେତେକ;
ଯେତେକ ଇତ୍ୟାଦି।)</p>
<p>8। (ସଂଖ୍ୟାବାଚକ ଶବ୍ଦ ସଙ୍ଗେ ଯୁକ୍ତ)—(ଅମୁକ) ସଂଖ୍ୟାର
ପୂରକ—
8. In the place of a certain
number e.g. third; fifth.</p>
<p>(ଯଥା—ତିନିକ ପଣିକିଆର ପାଞ୍ଚକ ଖନ୍ଦା ବୋଲି ଯାଅ।)</p>
<p>9। (ପରିମାଣବାଚକ ସର୍ବନାମ ସଙ୍ଗେ ଯୁକ୍ତ)—ପ୍ରାୟ
9. Approximately.</p>
<p>(ଯଥା—ଏତକ; ସେତକ; ଯେତେକ; କେତେକ ଇତ୍ୟାଦି।)</p></sense></gramGrp>
</entry>
```

Comment: Your xml is not well formed.  Well formed means the xml has only one root tag.  You have two root tags p and entry.  XML specification says that Well Formed is an attribute (only one root tag).  I interpreted the specification that xml is valid when it is Well Formed. Others, disagree with me and say Well Formed is a hard requirement.  Some XML libraries will give error with Non Well Formed while other libraries have options to ignore warning.  A lot of log files use XML format and often are not well formed because new entries are appended to the xml instead of adding before final tag.

Comment: @jdweng perhaps you are referring to the difference between a well-formed document and a well-formed entity. I'm afraid the way you have described it (in particular, introducing the word "valid" which has a technical meaning; and also, suggesting that there is room for disagreement) is not very helpful.

Comment: @MichaelKay : Had this discussion at another posting a few weeks ago.  Reading the specification for XML my interpretation is "well formed" is an attribute of valid xml (a subset).  The other person interpretation was "well formed" was a requirement.  The specification clear say "well formed" is an attribute.  So is an attribute a requirement or an option?  Non well formed is used in lots of log files and the Net Library XmlReader has option for allowing Non Well Formed XML (fragmented).

Comment: @jsweng You should probably raise a separate question if you are confused about this, rather than commenting on someone else's question.

Answer (score 1):

An XML document **must** have a [single root element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56674356/290085).  Yours has two (`p` and `entry`) and is therefore not [*well-formed*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134494/290085).  To correct, remove either the `p` or `entry` element, or wrap both in a single root element.

### See also

- [How to fix error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46355454/290085)
- [XML - Document cannot contain multiple root elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44592719/290085)

Comment: And more specifically, what the error message means is that the parser has found the close tag of the `p` element and treats that as being the end of the XML document. It then goes to check that there is nothing after the end of the XML document, and finds the `entry` start tag, and reports the error accordingly.

Comment: See my comment under OPs posting for my interpretation of "Well Formed".

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to parse the content you have shown, it's worth noting that although it is not a well-formed XML document, it *is* a well-formed XML entity (sometimes called an XML fragment), which means it can be incorporated into an XML document using an entity reference. There are several ways you might parse it:

(a) Check whether the parser you are using has options to parse an XML fragment rather than a document.

(b) Wrap an enclosing start and end tag around the content prior to parsing.

(c) Create a wrapper document that references the fragment using an entity reference such as `&fragment;` (declaring the entity in the DTD), and then parse the wrapper document.